# Spring Boot Hikar - Multi Datasource java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

Application is running fine for few hours and started facing below exception:

> "java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:515)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2104)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2034)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953) at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838) at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820) at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652) at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647) at
> org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2131)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
> at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)

---

Code for calling query:

```
@Autowired
private final EntityManager entityManager;

void someMethod() {
var q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
var rs = q.getResultList(); // exception at this line in stack trace
// other code
}
```

We recently added multiple data sources following this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources). Any chance it's causing an issue? Unable to prove some point though. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When using a **connection pool**, make sure to always close your connection and request a new one for every query. Holding a connection can cause the pool to close it after its idle timeout.

In Hikari you are not given an actual connection but a proxy implementation, where the underlying resources are managed internally by Hikari, so reusing this connection is bound to cause problems.

If this problem is caused by a library that badly manages connections, then a fallback solution would be to configure Hikari to allow underlying connections to be in an idle state indefinitely. This, however, is suboptimal.

Comment: Its spring boot and I am using EntityManager bean for creating native queries and executing them. No direct connections in the code.